# Prettier Not Working for Rust Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, prettier, prettier-vscode

I installed the Rust Prettier extension: https://github.com/jinxdash/prettier-plugin-rust but it is not formatting my rust files when I save.

I see this icon in VS Code in the Status Bar at the bottom-right indicating that Prettier is disabled when I click on a rust file: [image: prettier disablied]

This is usually what it looks like for me like if I click on a JavaScript file:
[image]

I also ran `npm install --global prettier-plugin-rust prettier` per the docs.

This is just showing the VS Code extension I've installed:
[image]

From VS Code Output

```
["INFO" - 10:35:08 PM] Extension Name: esbenp.prettier-vscode.
["INFO" - 10:35:08 PM] Extension Version: 9.10.3.
```

What's going on? Why is Prettier disabled on Rust files?

Could Rust files need to be enabled in the VS Code or Prettier settings?

Please let me know if I am missing any relevant information in the comments, thank you.

Comment: What happens when you click on the O with a slash through it?

Comment: Then it turns back to the check marks icon but as soon as I click on the rust file to edit it the icon turns back to the O with slash....

Comment: Have you restarted VScode since installing prettier?

Comment: Yes I have restarted VScode since installing prettier and the rust extension and it still doesn't work (ie same behavior as in the original post)

Comment: just curious, why not use the built in rust formatter `cargo fmt`?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to settings.json

```
{
    "[rust]": {
        "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "jinxdash.prettier-rust"
    }
}
```

Comment: you save me. thanks u so much.